# build tex file with pdflatex from other path

Tags: graphics, paths

I have such a structure:

```
..path..\pyt\go.py
..path..\tex\base\base.sty
..path..\tex\base\img\1.jpg
..path..\tex\book\book1.tex
..path..\tex\book\images\img.pdf
..path..\tex\book\bin\
..path..\tex\book\pdfs\
```

inside book1.tex there is:

```
\includegraphics{images/img.pdf}
```

from go.py (python script) i call commands:

```
set TEXINPUTS="..\\tex\\base"
pdflatex -quiet "..\\tex\\book\\book1.tex" -output-directory "..\\tex\\book\\bin\\"
```

but build fails because: File 'images/img.pdf' is not found

How can i tell *pdflatex* to read paths inside tex files as relative to its path..?
(But this base.sty - can take its 1.jpg file which is attached like: img/1.jpg)
If i remove image, everything builds succesfully.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answear!

inside ***book1.tex*** file just add `\graphicspath` command with two paths:

```
\graphicspath{{images/}{../book/images/}}
```

First path is valid from **.tex** files folder (usefull for manual build)
The second path is valid from build scripts folder.
Finally, images are included just by their filenames:

```
\includegraphics{img.pdf}
```

Comment: I was halfway through that recommendation however it may help to consider expanding to include {../..//} which should include all subdirectories below grandparent directory, however beware that could also search in unwanted sibling directories

Comment: It would be **much** better to change to the directory of your main file and to start the compilation from there.

Comment: i will try it.. as i understood: in go.py i change the folder and then set the texinput and run pdflatex? If so... it does not work for me.